# Rcmdr in R 3.0.1 asks to install rgl package everyime I open Rcmdr

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, r

I have installed R 3.0.1 in my Ubuntu 12.04 Laptop.

---

I started R as root by `sudo R`, then installed Rcmdr package by the following command:

`install.packages("Rcmdr", dependencies = TRUE)`

but everytime I run Rcmdr by `library(Rcmdr)`, it says that the package rgl is not installed, and asks to install it.

I do, but next time when I run Rcmdr, it again asks to install rgl. What should I do?

Comment: found a solution. Dowmloaded the rgl package and kept the folder in the location where Rcomdr folder is. Now Rcmdr isn't asking for installation of the rgl package anymore.

Comment: please write your solution to this up as an answer and accept it so that others may benefit from your experience. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. Downloaded the `rgl` package and kept the folder in the location where `Rmdr` folder is. Now `Rcmdr` isn't asking for installation of the `rgl` package anymore.